# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli)

Tags: integration, smooks, exec-maven-plugin

Im working on **Smooks - Camel Integration**.Im stuck with an error.The Build Fails 
 when I try to Run it using **mvn exec:java**

---

**[ERROR]:**
    Failed to execute goal **org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli)** on project 
    camel-example-smooks-integration:

**My console log reads as follows:**

```
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException

C:\apache-camel-2.11.0\examples\camel-example-smooks-integration>mvn exec:java
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.camel:camel-example-smooks-integration:bundle:2.11.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate   
declaration of plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin @ line 138, column 9

[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of 
 your build.

[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed 
projects.

[WARNING]

[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CAMEL SMOOKS-INTEGRATION 2.11.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) @ camel-example-smooks-integration >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:cleanVersions (versions) @ camel-example-smooks-
 integration ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) @ camel-example-smooks-integration <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) @ camel-example-smooks-integration ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.229s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Aug 01 20:29:09 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/22M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli) on    
project camel-example-smooks-integration: An exception occured while executing the Java class. 
C:\apache-camel-2.11.0\examples\camel-example-smooks -integration\src\main\java\example\Main -> 
[Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following 
articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**My POM.xml reads as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>camel-example-smooks-integration</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>CAMEL SMOOKS-INTEGRATION</name>

    <description>An example for showing Camel Smooks Integration</description>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.milyn</groupId>
            <artifactId>milyn-smooks-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for testing -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>


                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>target/classes/features.xml</file> 
                                    <type>xml</type>
                                    <classifier>features</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>  
                </executions>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>C:\apache-camel-2.11.0\examples\camel-example-smooks-  
                        integration\src\main\java\example\Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>osgi.org.springframework.batch</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>*</Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                    <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

**I've tried following things so far to eliminate this error, havent got any success yet.**

```
1.DownGraded the JDK from  Version 1.7 to jdk1.6.0_18

2.Added the **main class** in the **plugin for org.codehaus.mojo**

          <configuration>
            <mainClass>C:\apache-camel-2.11.0\examples\camel-example-smooks-integration\src\main\java\example\Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Looking for suggestions to fix this issue

Comment: Try `mvn -X exec:java` to enable full debug logging, you should have more info

Comment: I have the same problem (with a newer version) but JUST when I try to run the project from a new class with PSVM on it (to test some methods).
If I run it from the original "main" class this error doesn't show up.

`Main1.class` (1st and only class with PSVM), calling methods on Another.class, but If I try to run `Another.class` (with PSVM) directly, throws the error

Comment: Mr. Pineda said it well here and this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59765574/netbeans-maven-failed-to-execute-goal-on-project

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem.

As it turned out, I ran

```
mvn clean package install
```

Correct way is

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: where I can do this in Netbeans?

Comment: I do not use NetBeans. I ran the command in the command line. As I remember, Eclipse allows to create build tasks.

Comment: These commands are equivalent. Maven will run all preceding steps in [the lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), so specifying `install` means that `package` will be run as well, and `compile`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that you have declare twice the exec-maven-plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>C:\apache-camel-2.11.0\examples\camel-example-smooks-  
      integration\src\main\java\example\Main< /mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

...

```
< plugin>
    < groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    < artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    < version>1.2</version>
< /plugin>
```

Comment: Hey Pith, I tried deleting the duplicate entries for  < groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
its still failing with same error:

Comment: You have delete the entire plugin, not only the groupId ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but after deleting the old plugin for 
org.codehaus.mojo it worked.

I use this

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with 'org.codehaus.mojo'-'jaxws-maven-plugin': could not resolve dependencies. Fortunately, I was able to do a Project > Clean in Eclipse, which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem in IntelliJ...
1) Put your .fxml files into ***resources*** directory
2) In the Start method define the path to .fxml file in the following way:
`Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));`
The `/` seemed to solve this problem for me :)