# ClassNotFoundException when building application with maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven

In a spring boot project who use maven. A class is not found

A part of my pom

```
<groupId>com.acme.pay</groupId>
<artifactId>ms.billing</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ms.billing</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <default.package>com.acme.pay.ms.billing</default.package>
</properties>
```

Structure of the project

```
com
  acme
    pay
      ms
        billing
          domain
          v2
          BillingServiceApplication.java
```

When I start application, I get this error

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.acme.pay.ms.BillingServiceApplication
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.acme.pay.ms.BillingServiceApplication
>   Command execution failed.
>
> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project ms.billing: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

It seem it don't seem in the correct path.

Comment: com.acme.pay.ms.BillingServiceApplication seems to be wrong. Your package has another "billing": com.acme.pay.ms.billing.BillingServiceApplication - beside that there is no need for the exec plugin. The spring-boot-maven plugin already contains a run mojo to start the application.

Comment: Your package is wrongly mentioned and compiler is looking into wrong place. Either update your class into right package or update the package name.

Comment: Can you please confirm if your application is 'Spring Boot' application?
If yes, then while running your application as 'Java application', just choose the main file as 'BillingServiceApplication'. There is no problem with your pom file. 

If no, then could you please share your pom file with all dependencies? I think that you need to change the version of the dependency 
'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin'.

Comment: Please share code of `BillingServiceApplication`

Comment: May be issue coming at building the project due to your package and main class configuration is not perfect.

-Make package name like this 
    "com.acme.pay.ms.billing.BillingServiceApplication"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to your `artifactId` having a `.` character in it.  I've never seen an artifactId formatted like that and I think it might be messing up the path resolution. Usually people use `-` as a separator when they want to make an artifactId more readable (as per `commons-math` in the maven guide linked below).

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

> choose whatever name you want with lowercase letters and no strange symbols

Comment: I use `.` in my `artifactId` often without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm if your application is '**Spring Boot**' application?

***If yes***, then while running your application as 'Java application', just choose the main file as 'BillingServiceApplication'. There is no problem with your pom file.

***If no***, then could you please share your pom file with all dependencies?

I think that you need to change the **version of the following dependency**

```
'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin'.
```

Just check the link for similar question on stackoverflow:

[Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java (default-cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011494/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin1-2java-default-cli/33732632)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

did you annotate your class with **@Component**, **@Services** etc 
OR
if your class out of the scan scoop you could included it via

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.acme.pay.ms.billing")
@Configuration
public class SpringComponentScanApp {
```

Or you could use xml as in your case via

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.acme.pay.ms.billing" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Package of `BillingServiceApplication` should be `com.acme.pay.ms.billing.BillingServiceApplication`