# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, runtime-error

After Installing Java in my computer I'm getting the following error in NetBeans

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project Project1: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

after running the following code

```
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name is " + name);
    }
}
```

If I only run the `System.out.println("What is your name?");` line of code, the program works perfectly.

---

I have found the same (or similar) mistake in multiple posts in this website, but I'm so new to programming that I do not understand the answers. For example, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011494/failed-to-execute-goal-org-codehaus-mojoexec-maven-plugin1-2java-default-cli) post the most upvoted answer states that "As it turned out, I ran mvn clean package install. Correct way is mvn clean install", and in the comments he follows that " I ran the command in the command line. As I remember, Eclipse allows to create build tasks."

I've been trying to figure out what some of the answers mean without much success. Could someone explain to a beginner-level programmer how this issue is to be solved?

Comment: new to programming? Why do you need maven for this "hello world" example? Just create a Java Project without maven to learn. Then you can learn fully about maven later.

Comment: Please add your pom.xml and the command you ran to your question.